# AEM Predicate - how to check if property starts with / contains string?

Tags: aem, query-builder

I'm using query builder to search for images in DAM. I use predicates to do that. I'm trying to check metadata dam:MIMEtype property, to return all nodes which starts from image/.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.html) to achieve the same.

Assuming that you are searching the path `/content/dam` for all `dam:Asset`'s whose `dam:MIMEtype` starts with `image/` the query would be

```
path=/content/dam
type=dam:Asset
property=jcr:content/metadata/dam:MIMEtype
property.value=image/%
property.operation=like
p.limit=-1
```

The corresponding XPATH query would be

```
/jcr:root/content/dam//element(*, dam:Asset)
[
jcr:like(jcr:content/metadata/@dam:MIMEtype, 'image/%') 
]
```

You can try executing the above query in your instance's query debugger(`/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html`) and verify if the results are fine.

[PredicateEvaluator Docs](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/PredicateEvaluator.html) and the [QueryBuilder API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/dam/customizing_and_extendingcq5dam/query_builder.html) might provide more insights on writing queries.

Comment: for `ends-with` or `contains`, we can try `%image` and `%image%` respectively.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp